# Rewrite url to redirect host

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So i want to redirect:

1. `first.com` to `second.com`
2. `first.com/something` to `second.com/redir.php?q=something`

So i did

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*first.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://second.com/redir.php?q=$1 [R,L]
```

But its only working for 1, it's sending to `second.com/redir.php?q=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect the 2nd case to be fine with your rules. For the first one you can add another rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*first.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://second.com/ [R,L]
```

Comment: thanks, it's working for 1, but not for 2. it gives Not Found, The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: ok nevermind.. it works.. there was a #wordpress block, i just moved it above

Comment: NB this rule will have to go before the one given in the question.